# What is the logic behind Android device scaling ratio (3:4:6:8:12:16)?

Tags: android, drawable, scaling

According to [android developer reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html):

> follow the 3:4:6:8:12:16 scaling ratio between the six generalized
>   densities. For example, if you have a bitmap drawable that's 48x48
>   pixels for medium-density screens, all the different sizes should be:
>
> - 36x36 (0.75x) for low-density
> - 48x48 (1.0x baseline) for medium-density
> - 72x72 (1.5x) for high-density
>
> ...

Why is it 0.75x and not 0.95x?

**What is the logic behind these numbers?**

Comment: `why 0.75x why not 0.95x` because 120 dpi is 3/4 of 160 dpi.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, there are four densities: ldpi, mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi (4). Take the size of your drawable bitmap, 48 in that case, then divide by 4, then use those numbers as multipliers: 3: 4: 6: 8: 12: 16 and you will have the resolution in each density.

48 / 4 = 12 * 3 = 36 ( 36 = 0,75% of 48 )

That's what I understood. Good luck.